# strpos works with php 8.1 not php 7.2

Tags: php, strpos

Hi this code is working on php 8.1
`PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Apr  7 2022 17:46:26) (NTS)`
but not with
`PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.11 (cli) (built: Mar  2 2022 17:52:35) ( NTS )`

there is the code :

```
if(strpos(file_get_contents('cache2.db'),$link) == false) 
            {
                file_put_contents($i.'.png',file_get_content_curl($link));
                file_put_contents('cache2.db', $link. PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            }
```

With php 7.2, it open cache2.db and write in it, even if the link is in it. With php 8.1, it works as espected. I don't understand why, thanks for your help.

Comment: Change `==` to `===`. Otherwise you get the wrong result when the position is `0`.

Comment: From the [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) manual: "_Warning

This function may return Boolean false, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to false. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function._"

Comment: Same thing, it works with my local conf, php 8.1, not on my server php 7.2

Comment: That function works the same between those versions: https://3v4l.org/Hrv5b. If you get different results, it's most likely something else.

Comment: same thing with !== false, it works on my config with php8.1... yes it is something else but i don't understand what is it